# "Xml Parsing error" when trying to browse a SharePoint site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, moss

Well, I am getting this error "Xml parsing Error: No element found:" when I am trying to browse a SharePoint Site.

THe SharePoint site is a pretty fresh installation, with no custom code running in the page.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Update: Since it was a relatively fresh installation of SharePoint, i reinstalled sharepoint but the issue still remained. Guess its an ASP.NET/IIS issue...  Any clue

Comment: Is it the root site and if so, have you checked IIS to see if the site was extended properly? Was the virtual directory set up and the Web Application created?

Comment: You can reply if you solved your problem and tick you own answer. It will give solution to others facing the same problem.